# Plotting data from specific column

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have data like this:

> 1406998993.147     73 TCP_MISS/200 22284,
>
> 1406998993.158    109 TCP_MISS/200 83827,
>
> 1406998993.197    111 TCP_MISS/200 57020,

If I want to plot the column 1 and the column 2, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the formatting that you most probably have, presumably in a file:

```
filecontent = StringReplace[
   "1406998993.147 73 TCP_MISS/200 22284, 1406998993.158 109 TCP_MISS/200 83827, 1406998993.197 111 TCP_MISS/200 57020", 
   RegularExpression[",\\s*"] -> "\n"
]
```

this will convert the string to a Mathematica list:

```
data = ImportString[filecontent,"Table"]
```

and this will plot the second column over the first:

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All,{1,2}]]]
```

or, to plot either column on its own use e.g.:

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All,1]]]
ListPlot[data[[All,2]]]
```

To import the data from an actual file you would use `Import[filename,"Table"]` instead of the above `ImportString`...